# T-SQL Check whether a file exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Am trying to check whether a file exists, and store the result in a variable. Am expecting the variable `@file_exists` to be either true or false, but am getting the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'xp_fileexist C:\ABC\myfile_20200521.xls, ' to data type int

What is it that am doing wrong?

```
DECLARE @filepath VARCHAR(MAX), 
        @file_exists INT = 0, 
        @sql VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @filepath = (SELECT CONCAT('C:\ABC\myfile_',convert(varchar,getdate(),112),'.xls'));

SET @sql = N'xp_fileexist '+@filepath+ N', '+@file_exists+ N' OUT' 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

IF(@file_exists = 1)
    PRINT 'File exists'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have run into a case of [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). The statement

```
SET @sql = N'xp_fileexist '+@filepath+ N', '+@file_exists+ N' OUT'
```

contains `@file_exists` which is declared as an `INT`, therefore all of the strings need to be converted to `INT` values for addition.

What you appear to want is:

```
declare @FilePath as NVarChar(256), @FileExists as Int = 0;

set @FilePath = Concat( N'C:\ABC\myfile_', Convert( NVarChar(8), GetDate(), 112), N'.xls' );

execute master.dbo.xp_fileexist @FilePath, @FileExists output;

if ( @FileExists = 1 )
    print 'File exists.'
```

Note that the data type specified in the `Convert` has a length.

Comment: This is it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `concat()` the function:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT(N'xp_fileexist ', @filepath, N', ', @file_exists, N' OUT')
```

That way, `+` won't be interpreted as a string.

You could also pass in the values as parameters, which would be recommeneded.

Comment: Are you sure you want to concatenate the _value_ of `@file_exists`? Shouldn't the variable be passed as an `output` parameter? And `@filepath`, though not as `output`?

Comment: @HABO . . . I'm a little unclear on what the OP is really trying to do.  This fixes the reported issue of `+`being interpreted (shockingly) as addition.